# Is a finite measure tight iff it is a Radon measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a Hausdorff space and $\mu$ be a finite measure on $E$. Remember that $\mu$ is called

- **tight** if for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ with $$\mu(K^c)<\varepsilon\tag1;$$
- **Radon** if for all $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ with $$\mu(B\setminus K)<\varepsilon\tag2.$$

It is easy to verify that $\mu$ is tight iff $$\mu(E)=\sup_{K\subseteq E\text{ is compact}}\mu(K)\tag{1'}$$ and $\mu$ is Radon iff $$\forall B\in\mathcal B(E):\mu(B)=\sup_{\substack{K\subseteq E\text{ is compact}\\ K\subseteq B}}\mu(K)\tag{2'}.$$

Now, on page 11 of *Probability in Banach Spaces - Stable and Infinitely Divisible Distributions* by *Werner Linde*, we can find the following paragraph:

[image]

So, on the one hand he is calling $\mu$ *Radon* if $(1')$ hold - which is equivalent to my definition of $\mu$ being tight. On the other hand, he is claiming that this already implies $(2')$ - which is equivalent to my definition of $\mu$ being Radon.

In summary, it seems like he's claiming that both notions coincide. So, my question is: How do we show that? I don't understand why $(1')$ implies $(2')$. Let me note that he's assuming that $E$ is a metric space. If that's important, feel free to show the desired claim under this additional assumption.

And if the claim is indeed true: Does this extend to families $\mathcal F$ of finite measures on $E$? (Remember that in that case $\mu$ in $(1)$ and $(2)$ is replaced by the corresponding supremum over all $\mu\in\mathcal F$.)

Comment: Radon measures are regular (in particular inner regular) measures. So yes, finite Radon measures are tight.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you for your comment. Please note that I'm not asking to show that "Radon implies tight" (this is trivial; we simply need to take $B=E$ in $(2)$). What I'm asking is the converse: The reference I've cited seems to claim "tight implies Radon" and I don't get why this should hold.

Comment: The converse is a Theorem by Ulam. I believe this is done in Dudley's book of real analysis and probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author gives a reference to this result - Theorem II.3.1. in *Parthasarathy, K. R. - Probability Measures on Metric Spaces (1967)*. That is, any finite tight Borel measure on a metric space $E$ is automatically a Radon measure. Specifically, such a measure is (inner) regular in the sense that for any Borel set $A$,
$$
\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(C):C\subseteq A, C\text{ is closed}\}.
$$
Together with tightness, this implies that for each $\epsilon>0$, we can find a compact set $K_{\epsilon}\subseteq A$ s.t. $\mu(A\setminus K_{\epsilon})<\epsilon$ (i.e., take $K_{\epsilon}=C_{\epsilon}\cap B_{\epsilon}$, where $C_{\epsilon}\subseteq A$ is a closed set with $\mu(A\setminus C_{\epsilon})<\epsilon/2$ and $B_{\epsilon}\subseteq E$ is a compact set with $\mu(E\setminus B_{\epsilon})<\epsilon/2$).